# Haskell: List fusion, where is it needed?

Tags: optimization, haskell, lazy-evaluation, fusion

Lets say we have the following:

```
l = map f (map g [1..100])
```

And we want to do:

```
head l
```

So we get:

```
head (map f (map g [1..100]))
```

Now, we have to get the first element of this. `map` is defined something like so:

```
map f l = f (head l) : (map f (tail l))
```

So then we get:

```
f (head (map g [1..100]))
```

And then applied again:

```
f (g (head [1..100]))
```

Which results in

```
f (g 1)
```

No intermediate lists are formed, simply due to laziness.

Is this analysis correct? And with simple structures like this:

```
foldl' ... $ map f1 $ map f2 $ createlist
```

are intermediate lists ever created, even without "list fusion"? (I think laziness should eliminate them trivially).

---

The only place I can see a reason to keep a list is if we did:

```
l' = [1..100]
l = map f (map g l')
```

Where we might want to keep `l'`, if it is used elsewhere. However, in the `l'` case above here, it should be fairly trivial for the compiler to realise its quicker just to recalculate the above list than store it.

Answer (score 7):

In your `map` example the list cells are created and then immediately garbage-collected. With list fusion no GC or thunk manipulation (which are both not free) is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Fusion benefits most when the intermediate data structures are expensive. When the structure being passed is lazy, and accessed in a sequential manner, the structures may be relatively cheap (as is the case with lists).

- For lazy structures, fusion removes the constant factor of creating a thunk, and immediately garbage collecting it.
- For strict structures, fusion can remove *O(n)* work.

The greatest benefits are thus for strict arrays and similar structures. However, even fusing lazy lists is still a win, due to increased data locality, due to fewer intermediate structures being allocated as thunks.